# How to disable cut, copy, paste, rename, etc from the Windows Registry?

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I'm trying to create a software in VB.Net as my uni project to disable the following from a Windows 7 pc. I think they have to be disabled from the context menu of the Windows Registry, but instead of disabling the whole context menu, I'd like to disable the following individually.

- Cut, copy, paste, rename, delete, open, print, share, create shortcut, open with, send to, new, properties.

I want to give users the option of disabling them selectively/individually via checkboxes so those options will be disabled in the right-click of a mouse.

My problem is I don't know which is the right key to disable as the registry is so huge & some keys are similiarly named.

Could anyone help me to say what are the exact key locations of the above-mentioned right-click functions in the Windows Registry or how to go about this ?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I wonder why you need to do such a thing?

Answer (score 7):

The deep flaw in the assumptions made in this question is that the context menu is configured by registry entries.  It is not.  Windows allows modifying a window's context menu by sending the WM_CONTEXTMENU message.  Code, not config.  If you are not happy with the default implementation of that message then you *subclass* the window procedure and provide your own message handler for that message so you can display your own context menu. This is core to the way Windows works.

Modifying the context menu of a program you didn't write is possible too but much more complicated.  You use SetWindowsHookEx() to inject a DLL into the other process.  You cannot write a DLL like that in VB.NET, it requires native code.  Because that process won't have the CLR loaded to run your managed code.